# Why does PWA cache storage usage does not go down?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Every time I put a request to the storage the cache usage grows (judging by the indicator)

```
Cache.put(request, response)
```

But, when I delete a request from the storage the usage does not go down.

```
Cache.delete(request, options)
```

I check the list of the cached resources and the request is not there, so it's successfully deleted, but the indicator tells another story.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cache.add and Cache.delete both return a promise. Make sure it is resolved.

```
Cache.delete(request, options).then(result => {
    // got final result
}).catch(err => {
    // got error
});
```

Additionally you can see if you operations are changing the cache by opening it in the [Application Dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftq1f.png)